Choosing Git Version Control Strategy for Existing Project Structure: Monorepo vs. Multirepo with Submodules
I am working on an existing project where I need to implement Git version control. The challenge is deciding whether to use a monorepo or multirepo strategy. Here is the current folder structure, which must remain unchanged:
/pipeline
  /project1
  /project2
  /project3
  /etc.
  /sharedcode1
  /sharedcode2
  /etc.

Details:
Each project typically has its own developer or, at most, a small team of up to three developers.
The projects are mostly independent of each other, with the exception of the /sharedcode directories, which are utilized across multiple projects.
Considerations:
I am leaning against using a monorepo because the projects and development teams are mostly independent.
My main concern with using a multirepo approach and Git submodules is the handling of submodules located outside the main project directory. For example, if I want /project1 to include /sharedcode1 and /sharedcode2 as submodules, these shared code directories are located outside of /project1.
When a developer clones /project1 into their local development environment, I want them to automatically get all the necessary submodules, resulting in a structure like this:
/local_dev_environment
  /project1
  /sharedcode1
  /sharedcode2

Question:
Is it feasible to manage submodules located outside the main project directory using Git? If not, what do you suggest?
Thank you in advance.

@phd I did refactor my original post to be much more readable. What else can i do? Do you imply my question is stupid or not worth it to be answered? That would say allot for you if you did tho.. And to aswer your question, i believe it is. If it gets closed... well stackoverflow is not the same as before and i don't mean that in a good way.

@phd fair enough. edited Thanks for the feedback.

There's nothing built into git that gets you the project structure you're looking for.  There are tools that attempt to solve that problem, but asking for recommendations is off-topic.

Is it mandatory to use exactly the folder structure you mentioned? The easiest way may be to introduce a dedicated folder for placing dependencies in the each project's repo. Then bind the submodules inside that dedicated folder. Something like env_root\deps\<submodules goes here>, env_root\project\<project code goes here>. The git root is an env_root folder.

@StephenNewell oh well.. i guess i should just make a monorepo then. Anyway can you point to the other solutions that i can read up on? thanks

@Serg sadly yes, it is mandatory. I've spoken with the team and no one wants to change the folder structure or feels safe about doing so. This is an old pipeline from 20y ago and no one planned of having git version control back in the day and it just grew bigger and bigger. Many paths are hardcoded, even some that are not in the root folder (from elsewhere).. it's a mess..

Hmm. I just realized, that you can get the folder structure you want just by moving the git root. So, for the project1 you will have env_root\project1\<project_code> and then bind the submodules directly into the root env_root\sharedcode1, env_root\sharedcode2,.... If you have no files (not folders) that you need directly in the root (like env_root\my_shared_text_file.txe) then everything should work.

@Serg that would be great if it works, and no, there are no files directly inside /pipeline that we need.
But i am not sure how to bind these (i am not that experienced with git sadly). Care to write a full answer please with steps? Thank you!

So, from given description and desired project folder layout:
/local_dev_environment
  /project1/[proj_file_1,...]
  /sharedcode1/[shared1_file_1,...]
  /sharedcode2/[shared2_file_1,...]

we can do the following:

place each shared folder into the separate submodule. Files should be placed in the root of the repo

sharedcode1 repo contains files /[shared1_file_1,...] directly in the repo root.
sharedcode2 repo contains files /[shared2_file_1,...] directly in the repo root.


place the project files into the folder inside the dedicated project repo, so the repo project1 will contain files like /project1/[proj_file_1,...] (note that all files placed into the project1 folder inside the repo, not in the root).
checkout the submodules in the root of the project repo:

git submodule add https://<sharedcode1_repo_url>
git submodule add https://<sharedcode2_repo_url>
git submodule update --init
you can adjust the submodule add command to place the code in the folder with a desired name, if this name does not match the repo name.



